# Incorrect behaviour when selecting chips in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.12 the behaviour when selecting chips in a chip-list is incorrect. See ([next.plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/dQKbJfgLiSjDKA6WwAZ1?p=preview)) and try to toggle the chips. This used to work in at least 2.0.0-beta.10. When selecting a chip other previously selected chips may lose it selected styling.

I have this html code:

```
<mat-chip-list class="mat-chip-list-stacked">
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let chip of availableColors" selected="{{chip.selected}}"
  (click)="chip.selected = !chip.selected" [color]="chip.color">
    {{chip.name}}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

And Typescript:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'chips-stacked-example',
  templateUrl: 'chips-stacked-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['chips-stacked-example.css'],
})
export class ChipsStackedExample {
  color: string;

  availableColors = [
    { name: 'none', color: '', selected:true },
    { name: 'Primary', color: 'primary', selected:false },
    { name: 'Accent', color: 'accent', selected:true },
    { name: 'Warn', color: 'warn', selected:true }
  ];

}
```

I'm I doing anything wrong, e.g. using the (click) event? Note the the array's data is consistent. It's only the presentation which gets wrong.

Comment: Do you have any CSS? If so please add the part relevant for the buttons

Comment: Check the browser console

Comment: I only use https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css for styling.

Comment: There is an error in the console: Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to do with this github post: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005

What I suggest is putting your click call into a timeout AND using the changedetectorref item.

```
  changeMe(chip) {
    let vm =this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      chip.selected = !chip.selected
      vm._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    },10);
  }
```

I also needed to change a couple of things in the html:

```
<mat-chip-list class="mat-chip-list-stacked" [multiple]="true">
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let chip of availableColors; let i=index"  selected="{{availableColors[i].selected}}"
 (click)="changeMe(availableColors[i])" [color]="chip.color"  [value]="chip.name" [selectable]="true">
    {{chip.name}}
  </mat-chip>

</mat-chip-list>
```

Selectable was a boolean and how you are using it the multiple flag is required. I also included a value for completeness.

A full plunkr is here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/qD99AN?p=preview

The reason it was failing was mostly the change detection was clashing with the current "in play" detection so you have to manually do it your self. Also how you were using it you needed the multiple keyword.
Seems to be a overly fussy control from angular material. The docs aren't 100% either.
Anyway it's working now, see if it does for you.

Comment: [multiple]="true" made the difference. I didn't need that before. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yes it's slyly tagged onto the mat-chip-list docs. When they finally get to non-beta angular material they need some better examples and have a good round of docs "brush up". The chips one for instance is referring to "md" and "mat".

Comment: set [multiple]="true" on  mat-chip-list save my day.

Answer (score 1):

I had to select only one chip at a time like a radio button. I did it the following way. Might not be the best approach but served the purpose.

In html:

```
        <mat-chip-list [multiple]="false">
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let chip of filterChips; let i=index"  selected="{{filterChips[i].selected}}"
                      (click)="toggleChip(filterChips[i])" [value]="chip.name">
                {{chip.name}}
            </mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
```

In ts:

```
  filterChips = [
    { name: 'name1', selected: false },
    { name: 'name2', selected: false },
    { name: 'name3', selected: false },
    { name: 'name4', selected: false }
  ]

  toggleChip(chip) {
    this.filterChips.forEach(c => { chip.name !== c.name ? c.selected = false : c.selected = true; });
    this.applyFilter(chip.name);
  }
```